# Evolutionary explanation of the bicuspid on the left and tricuspid on the right

Tags: human-biology, evolution, cardiology

The left heart handles more pressure and logically it would make sens to have a valve with three leafs on the left (If I had got to choose, I'd have put three on both sides).

Other than being more susceptible to valvular disease (also because the pressure is higher on the left), the bicuspid having 2 leaves don't do any good (To my knowledge).

Since this is not the case, there might be some evolutionary constraints that might have caused this difference.

Any explanation according to valvular evolution along the phyla?

Comment: Logically it would be better to have less number of valves as pressure to be handled increases.

Comment: I agree more valves makes it structurally weaker.