# Different number of flaps in heart valves

Tags: human-biology, cardiology, human-evolution

Can anyone tell me why the different valves of heart have different number of flaps is it in any way related to evolution of homo sapiens.

Comment: This question has been asked before.. although still without an answer http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/52276/evolutionary-explanation-of-the-bicuspid-on-the-left-and-tricuspid-on-the-right